# npm install with local dependency returns TypeError when runnig

Tags: javascript, npm-install, datetimepicker

When I build my package with the default npm datetimepicker modules from the npm package repo everything works fine. But if I try to build with a local version, I ended with an error when I load the page saying that.
I downloaded the local package from git hub.

> Uncaught TypeError: eo.datetimepicker is not a function

Both my code and the datetimepicker have dependency on jquery (not sure if that's relevant).

The problem remains even if the datetimepicker package is identical to what npm gets from the repo ( I checkout the version that's in the npm repo)

For example, this works:

```
npm install 
npm run build
```

But this doesn't

```
npm install --save ../../datetimepicker
npm run build
```

I can see that in node_modules, a link is created for the jquery-datetimepicker module that points to the ../../datetimepicker folder where I cloned the repo.

In my code:

```
"use strict";

import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-toggle';
import '<package name>'

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css'
import 'jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.css'
```

My webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: "jquery",
       jQuery: "jquery"
   })
]
```

};

Comment: Have you tried running the `npm run build` in the `../../datetimepicker` directory too? Most likely the repository you have cloned doesn't provide the distributable code out of the box. On NPM there may be already distributable version, but it's not recommended to store distributable code in the repository (as it's generated by machine).

Comment: @DawidRusnak I did actually, even though build folder was committed to the repo.

Comment: So I disabled minimization and compared the 2 webpack outputs. Both include the datetime picker module, but the local version includes 2 versions of jquery.

Comment: I forced my module and datetimepicker to both use the same version of jquery - still getting 2 instances of the module included. Removing one by hand seems to fix my problem. Not sure why.